# Rails way for creating an endpoint accepting multiple objects at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I need to create an endpoint that accepts multiple objects at once. Example request (json body) below:

```
{
    "obd_bluetooth_events" : [
        {
            "car_id": 1,
            "obd_plugin_id": "1",
            "kind": "CONNECT",
            "date": 1422369149
        },
        {
            "car_id": 1,
            "obd_plugin_id": "1",
            "kind": "DISCONNECT",
            "date": 1422369149
        },
        {
            "car_id": 1,
            "obd_plugin_id": "1",
            "kind": "CONNECT",
            "date": 1422369149
        }
    ]
}
```

So in order to be able to pass an array to create method: `@obd_bluetooth_event.create(obd_bluetooth_events_params)`

I need to define obd_bluetooth_events_params method like this:

```
def obd_bluetooth_events_params
  params.permit(
    obd_bluetooth_events: [
      :car_id, 
      :obd_plugin_id, 
      :kind, 
      :date
    ]
  )[:obd_bluetooth_events]
end
```

After calling which i get:

```
Unpermitted parameters: obd_bluetooth_event
=> [{"car_id"=>1, "obd_plugin_id"=>"1", "kind"=>"CONNECT", "date"=>1422369149},
 {"car_id"=>1, "obd_plugin_id"=>"1", "kind"=>"DISCONNECT", "date"=>1422369149},
 {"car_id"=>1, "obd_plugin_id"=>"1", "kind"=>"CONNECT", "date"=>1422369149}]
```

Im wondering wether there is a more railsy way to permit an array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

`def obd_params
  params.require(:myparams).permit(:myarray => [])
end`

Works fine for me to permit arrays.
Hope this helps ;)